# "we are only given something" or "we are given only something"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, expressions

chapter 1 of the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" says

> The second main type of machine learning is the descriptive or
> unsupervised learning approach. **Here we are only given inputs**...

similar expressions

expression_1

Here we are **only** given inputs

expression_2

Here we are given **only** inputs

which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: These are exactly the same in this context.  Either can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference in meaning between the two.

"We are only given inputs." We might have expected something else to happen, but the only thing that happened was that we were given inputs.

"We are given only inputs." We might have expected to be given other things too, but the only thing we were given was inputs.

Do you see the difference? In this example, there probably is none. But imagine the same construction in a different context:

"I wanted my parents to give me support and encouragement, but they only bought me stuff." That is, I wanted them to do other things besides buy me stuff, but that was all they did.

"The rebels wanted weapons and ammo, but the outside world supplied them only medicine and humanitarian aid." They wanted to be supplied other things, but this was the only things they were given.

It can be a subtle difference. Especially if you use a general word like "given", because one can "give money" but one can also "give love" or "give moral support".

Answer (score -1):

"Only" is an emphatic word. The interest of the question is that it goes against what would be structurally expected.

You could attach **only** to different parts of the sentence for interesting effects: [S], here, we, are+given, inputs. (Note that **be+given** is not properly 2 words, but the *passive conjugation of give*)

1) Only,here we are given inputs.

2) Only here we are given inputs.

3) Here only we are given inputs.

4) Here we are only given inputs.

5) Here we are given only inputs.

Contrasting them together gives a clear idea of what I mean.
4 is the one more *idiomatic*, however syntactically it would contrast with:
Here we are only given inputs (but no one receives feedback).

Fun question ;)

Answer (score -1):

"We are only given something" posesses some ambiguity. It could mean:

1. "We are given only something" 
   That is, the set of things given to us is a set of size one, containing just that *something* and nothing else.

or

2. "We are only given something and no other relevant circumstances are true of us"
    An example of this would be "Rachel was given a lollipop and put in the stroller; Bobby was only given a lollipop."

It may be implied by context (or just assumed by the listener) that the range of other things the speaker is intending to exclude by the "only" is a range of given things, but strictly speaking, it could have the latter meaning, since if placed before "given" it's may be modifying the entire phrase "given something," whereas "given only something" removes ambiguity because "only" is applied directly to "something."

Comment: It sounds like you are implying that the "inputs" must be a set of size one.  If this isn't what you meant, please reword.